# Triggering JavaScript by hitting enter, enabling multiple searches/AJAX queries/DataTable displays without refreshing web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I have a web page with an AWS API interface to query an RDS Aurora MySQL Serverless database. When a user types in a SQL statement and hits the Query button, an AJAX request will be triggered, JSON will be returned and the test-table table below will be converted to a DataTable.

```
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <p>Please enter a SQL query below</p>
                        <p>Do not wrap your query in outer quotation marks.</p>
                        <p>For database structure information, please select "Learn About the Database" above.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
                        <div class="active-cyan-4 mb-4">
                            <input id="sql-placeholder" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Write SQL here..." aria-label="Search">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                        <button id="query-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="DisplayQuery()">Query</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <table id="test-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                </table>
            </div>
```

The JavaScript for the onclick="DisplayQuery()" function is below.

```
var DisplayQuery;
(function($) {
  DisplayQuery = function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '*****',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("access-control-allow-origin", "*")
            },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "sqlStatement": $('#sql-placeholder').val()
      }),
      contentType: 'application/json',

      success: function(response) {

        // Get columns labels as list of dictionaries colLabels
        var colLabels = [];
        for (i = 0; i < response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.resultSetMetadata.columnMetadata.length; i++) {
          colLabels.push({
            title: response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.resultSetMetadata.columnMetadata[i].name
          }); 
        };

        // Get data rows as array of arrays dataRows3
        var dataRows = response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.records;
        var dataRows2 = [];
        var dataRows3 = [];

        for (i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
          dataRows2.push(dataRows[i].values);
        };

        dataRows2.forEach(arr => {
          rowVals = [];
          arr.forEach(e => {
            Object.entries(e).forEach(k => rowVals.push(k[1]))
          });
          dataRows3.push(rowVals);
        });

        try {
          $('#test-table').destroy();
        } finally {

        // Write DataTable from colLabels and dataRows3
        $('#test-table').DataTable({
          data: dataRows3,
          columns: colLabels,
          scrollX: true
        });
      }
    },

      error: function ajaxError(error) {
        console.error('Error in query processing; please try again.');
      }
    })
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Is there a way to add to/rewrite this JavaScript so that the query can also be triggered by typing into the sql-placeholder and hitting enter instead of clicking on the query-button? Also, is there a way to allow multiple searches without having to reload the web page? In other words, if you query, then go type something new into the sql-placeholder and hit enter or click the query-button, a new query will be triggered, the previous results will be removed, and the new results will be displayed?

Comment: Wrap it in a form and catch the `submit` event? Or check `keypress` events for an `enter` key?

Comment: It definitely can be done. Could you provide more of what you've attempted? It's a bit of a back-and-forth question otherwise. A.e. Someone answers, you clarify, they edit, you clarify, they edit, you clarify, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keydown` event listener to check which key the user typed and if the key used was the one you want (in this case Enter) call the function.

[onkeypress reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)

For example:

```
document.getElementById('#sql-placeholder').onkeypress = function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which
  if (keyCode === '13') {
    // Enter pressed
    DisplayQuery()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I'm not sure if I should accept as answer and open a new question for the second part regarding multiple queries?

Comment: It should work out of the box with multiple queries, every time the user hits enter it will trigger the search function with the values from the input

Comment: Ah sorry I should have clarified: if you type out a viable query then hit enter or the Query button, and the results are return and populated in the datatable, and then you edit your query without reloading the page and hit enter or Query again, this is the error message: DataTables warning: table id=test-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: I had tried to solve this with the try .destroy() piece, but that does not seem to have worked.

Comment: Ah yes, this is a Datatables thing, the link you posted has some solutions on how to solve the issue. You can just pick one which fits your use case better.

Answer (score 1):

Either wrap them in a form and catch the submit event as Nick mentioned or a simple way is

```
$('#sql-placeholder').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
    DisplayQuery();
  }
})
```